# Unable to read from XML file using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to read from the XML file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parts>
    <item>CPU</item>
    <item>GPU</item>
    <item>PSU</item>
</parts>
```

My goal is to add the items to a DefaultDataModel so I can update a JList. However, when I get to my for each loop nothing is added to the list nor is anything printed to the console. Can someone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

```
public void load()
{
    // First clear the JLit before loading anything
    partList.clear();
    chosenList.clear();

    File file = new File("partsList.xml");

    try
    {
        // Setup JAXB to create a list of strings from the XML file
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parts.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        // Read the XML file
        List<String> parts = (List<String>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(parts);

        for (String item : parts)
        {
            chosenList.addElement(item);
            System.out.println(item);
        }

        list_1.setModel(chosenList);
        list_1.repaint();
    }

    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }       
}
```

**Parts.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Parts extends AbstractList<String>
{
    /* This allows me to have a single instantiation of this class for
     * adding the PC components before writing them to the XML file
     */

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public boolean add(String element)
    {
        return list.add(element);
    }

    @Override
    public String get(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your Parts class. Was it generated from a schema, or did you code it by hand?

Comment: I just uploaded it. Coded by hand.

Comment: Try changing your @XmlElement name to "parts" so it matches the actual element that represents the List<String> you are trying to unmarshal.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still printing `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your Parts class is incomplete. The get and size methods should be implemented.

```
@Override
public String get(int arg0) {
    return list.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return list.size();
}
```

Then, the unmarshalling gives you a Parts object, not a list of strings. So, it should have been:

```
Parts parts = (Parts) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
System.out.println(parts);

for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
    chosenList.addElement(parts.get(i));
    System.out.println(parts.get(i));
}
```

Comment: I guess I got so wound up in the parsing that I forgot to complete my methods. Thanks for the help! That worked perfectly.